# C# removing a line from file that starts with a specific word

Tags: c#, file, file-io, io, windows-forms-designer

What is an efficient and elegant way to remove a line from a file that starts with a specific word in C#? I know how to remove a line if it contains a specific word anywhere in the line, but I am having trouble removing a line that starts with a specific word. Thanks!

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\MyChangedFile.txt", File.ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt").Where(line => !line.StartsWith(myWord)));`

Comment: sounds like you're looking for the str.StartsWith("Whatever string") method. You can see some Microsoft examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we should define what "starts with a specific **word**" means.

- If word is just a *substring*, then `string.StartsWith` is enough;
- If word is consequent letters, then we can try *regular expressions*:

Code. Substring case:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string fileName = @"c:\myFile.txt";

 File.WriteAllLines(fileName, File
   .ReadLines(fileName)
   .Where(line => !line.StartsWith(myWord))
   .ToArray());
```

Regular expressions case:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string fileName = @"c:\myFile.txt";

 Regex regex = new Regex($@"^{Regex.Escape(myWord)}\b");

 File.WriteAllLines(fileName, File
   .ReadLines(fileName)
   .Where(line => !regex.IsMatch(line))
   .ToArray());
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks Dmitry!

Comment: @IDoNotKnowHowToProgram: please, check the code where you address (open, read or write) this file. It seems that you haven't close `Stream` or `Reader` / `Writer` somewhere. Since the file is not *properly closed* when my code tries to read and write it you have the exception

Comment: Tried deleting my old comment before you responded. Figured it out. I was using the old comment you had posted above, but the answer you posted works just fine. So now I am not getting the error: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` anymore. It seems the `.ToArray()` needed to be added at the end, or the `@`'s needed to be removed. Not sure which one fixed it. Thanks Dmitry!

Comment: @IDoNotKnowHowToProgram: `ToArray()` - materialization - is *required* if you write into the *same* file (or you'll get the exception). We read the file, *get the array* (file is closed now) and then write. If you drop `ToArray` you start reading and writing the *same* file in the *same moment* and this is the error

Comment: Ahhhh, thanks for the clarification @Dmitry Bychenko. Good to know!